# Hierarchy (bifurcations) in graphs

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Suppose we have the given network 'g1', which we get based on the set 'q1':

```
q1 = {{6545, 1044}, {6546, 1044}, {6536, 1044}, {6537, 1043}, {6529, 1044}, {6530, 1043}, {6528, 1044}, {6529, 1044}, {6528, 1044}, {6529, 1043}, {6527, 1044}, {6528, 1044}, {6522,1044}, {6523, 1043}, {6544, 1045}, {6545, 1044}, {6535,1045}, {6536, 1044}, {6526, 1045}, {6527, 1044}, {6521,1045}, {6522, 1044}, {6543, 1046}, {6544, 1045}, {6534,1046}, {6535, 1045}, {6525, 1046}, {6526, 1045}, {6521, 1046}, {6522, 1045}, {6520, 1046}, {6521, 1045}, {6517, 1046}, {6518, 1047}, {6542, 1047}, {6543, 1048}, {6542, 1047}, {6543, 1046}, {6535, 1047}, {6536, 1046}, {6534,1047}, {6535, 1047}, {6533, 1047}, {6534, 1047}, {6533, 1047}, {6534, 1046}, {6532, 1047}, {6533, 1047}, {6531, 1047}, {6532, 1047}, {6525, 1047}, {6526, 1048}, {6524, 1047}, {6525, 1047}, {6524, 1047}, {6525, 1046}, {6520, 1047}, {6521, 1046}, {6519, 1047}, {6520, 1047}, {6519, 1047}, {6520, 1046}, {6518, 1047}, {6519, 1047}, {6518, 1047}, {6518, 1048}, {6549, 1048}, {6550, 1049}, {6543, 1048}, {6544, 1049}, {6532, 1048}, {6533, 1049}, {6532, 1048}, {6533, 1047}, {6530, 1048}, {6531, 1047}, {6526, 1048}, {6527, 1049}, {6523, 1048}, {6524, 1047}, {6518, 1048}, {6518, 1049}, {6550, 1049}, {6551, 1050}, {6548, 1049}, {6549, 1048}, {6547, 1049}, {6548, 1049}, {6545, 1049}, {6546, 1050}, {6544, 1049}, {6545, 1049}, {6543, 1049}, {6544, 1049}, {6542, 1049}, {6543, 1049}, {6539, 1049}, {6540, 1050}, {6538, 1049}, {6539, 1049}, {6537, 1049}, {6538, 1049}, {6536, 1049}, {6537, 1049}, {6533, 1049}, {6534, 1050}, {6529, 1049}, {6530, 1048}, {6529, 1049}, {6529, 1050}, {6527, 1049}, {6528, 1050}, {6522, 1049}, {6523, 1048}, {6518, 1049}, {6519, 1050}, {6518, 1049}, {6518, 1050}, {6551, 1050}, {6551, 1051}, {6546, 1050}, {6547, 1049}, {6543, 1050}, {6544, 1049}, {6541, 1050}, {6542, 1049}, {6540, 1050}, {6541, 1050}, {6535, 1050}, {6536, 1049}, {6534, 1050}, {6535, 1050}, {6529, 1050}, {6529, 1051}, {6528, 1050}, {6529, 1051}, {6521, 1050}, {6522, 1049}, {6519, 1050}, {6520, 1051}, {6551, 1051}, {6551, 1052}, {6542, 1051}, {6543, 1050}, {6529, 1051}, {6529, 1052}, {6520, 1051}, {6521, 1052}, {6520, 1051}, {6521, 1050}, {6517, 1051}, {6518, 1050}, {6551, 1052}, {6552, 1052}, {6541, 1052}, {6542, 1051}, {6529,1052}, {6530, 1053}, {6521, 1052}, {6522, 1053}, {6540, 1053}, {6541, 1052}, {6538, 1053}, {6539, 1054}, {6531,1053}, {6532, 1054}, {6530, 1053}, {6531, 1054}, {6530, 1053}, {6531, 1053}, {6522, 1053}, {6522, 1054}, {6539, 1054}, {6540, 1053}, {6531, 1054}, {6532, 1055}, {6533, 1055}, {6534, 1054}, {6532, 1055}, {6533, 1056}, {6532, 1055}, {6533, 1055}, {6521, 1055}, {6522, 1054}, {6533, 1056}, {6533, 1057}, {6520, 1056}, {6521, 1055}, {6534, 1057}, {6535, 1056}, {6533, 1057}, {6534, 1057}, {6519, 1057}, {6520, 1056}, {6518, 1058}, {6519, 1057}, {6517, 1059}, {6518, 1058}};

linesObjects = Map[Line@# &, Partition[q1, 2]];
g1 = Graphics[linesObjects, ImageSize -> 500]
points = DeleteDuplicates[q1];
```

Then we build the graph 'graph':

```
pointIndex = First /@ PositionIndex[points];
vertexCoordinates = AssociationMap[Reverse, pointIndex];
edges = BlockMap[Apply[UndirectedEdge], pointIndex /@ q1, 2];
graph = Graph[edges, VertexCoordinates -> Normal@vertexCoordinates]
```

[image]

Graph 'graph' is the base graph. This is an example graph. Ultimately, graphs with a very large number of nodes will be tested.
Question: how to find a hierarchy for this graph as in this example:
[image]

I would add that I am not interested in hierarchy visualization but only statistics - it means: how many is '1', how many is '2' etc.
This is called 'Strahler stream order' hierarchy.

More details can be seen here:
[enter link description here](http://www.gitta.info/Accessibiliti/en/html/StructPropNetw_learningObject5.html).
I am interested in the hierarchys for the graph 'graph': 'Strahler stream order' (fig. 1), 'Horton stream order' (fig. 2) and 'Horton stream order' (fig. 3).
Thanks in advance for your help :)

I think it's worth starting by finding nodes with 1 degree:

```
highDegree = Keys@Select[degree, EqualTo[1]];
Curry[f_][y_][x_] := f[x, y];
nearest = Nearest[Normal@pointIndex];
within = (Curry[nearest][{All, #}]@*vertexCoordinates) &;
j1 = VertexList[graph];
j2 = Complement[j1, highDegree];
hh = HighlightGraph[graph, highDegree, VertexSize -> 0.7]
```

[image]

Next, nodes with 2 degree:

```
highDegree = Keys@Select[degree, EqualTo[3]];
Curry[f_][y_][x_] := f[x, y];
nearest = Nearest[Normal@pointIndex];
within = (Curry[nearest][{All, #}]@*vertexCoordinates) &;
j1 = VertexList[graph];
j2 = Complement[j1, highDegree];
hh2 = Show[hh, 
  HighlightGraph[graph, Style[highDegree, Blue], VertexSize -> 0.7]]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for editorial error. Shoud be: points = DeleteDuplicates[q1]; I have made the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has all the tools you need for this:

- [`IGStrahlerNumber`](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igstrahlernumber) computes the Strahler number for each vertex
- `IGStrahlerNumber` requires a directed out-tree as input, as the directions indicate the identity of the root. If you have an undirected graph, use [`IGOrientTree[graph, root]`](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igorienttree) to create the out-tree.
- If you want the Strahler number for each branch of the tree, not for each vertex, you can use [`IGSmoothen`](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igsmoothen) to contract branches consisting of multiple edges into a single edge.

Answer (score 1):

@ Szabolcs. To check the method I recreated the graph shown in the colored drawing (with squareds background):

```
data = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 5 <-> 7, 4 <-> 8,8 <-> 9, 8 <-> 11, 11 <-> 12, 12 <-> 13, 13 <-> 14, 13 <-> 15, 12 <-> 16, 16 <-> 17, 16 <-> 18, 11 <-> 19, 19 <-> 20, 19 <-> 21};
```

```
u1 = IGStrahlerNumber@IGOrientTree[Graph[data], 9]
y2 = Split[Sort[u1]];
numb = Table[{y2[[i, 1]], Length[y2[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Length[y2]}]
```

It seems the 'numb' results are different from the manual counting:(